# Interpretation of Multinomial Logistic Regression model fit in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution, deviance

I have fitted a multinomial logistic regression model in R. The data has 35 independent variables and the dependent variable has 3 levels.
I do not find information on how to interpret the outcome of the model. Here is the plot of the model after cross validation. How do I assess the multinomial deviance and how far is it from saturated model?
[image]

The summary of the fit is as follows:

```
Call:  cv.glmnet(x = xtr, y = ytr, alpha = 0, family = "multinomial",      type.multinomial = "ungrouped") 

Measure: Multinomial Deviance 

      Lambda Measure       SE Nonzero
min 0.004034  0.8741 0.003612      35
1se 0.028460  0.8775 0.003510      35
```

Comment: Does the summary function not give you the deviance values? I am pretty sure it does for a binomial logistic regression, and I recall having an easy time extracting deviance values when I was doing this about a year ago.

Comment: I have updated my question with the summary information of the fitted model. How can I interpret if  0.8741 at minimum lambda is a good result or not?